# I am an agent OF/FROM XXX company

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence-meaning

What is the difference between these two?

> Customer service representative: Hello, my name is Cassie, an agent **OF** XXX company, telling you about our latest offer...

And

> Customer service representative: Hello, my name is Cassie, an agent **FROM** XXX company, telling you about our latest offer...

Let's say you are "cold calling" potential clients. Do the sentences above both possible? -as it may have different meanings. Or it should have only one grammatical **preposition**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...**an agent** of **XXX company**...

Here "of" is used after the title/position of Cassie to describe the relationship between her and the organization she belongs to.

> ... **an agent** from **XXX company**...

"From" is used here to show that the agent Cassie is sent from the XXX company.

So, yes, the meaning differs. But both can fit in the example you provided.

I would choose "of" in your statement as Cassie is introducing herself, so it would be more reasonable for her to mention her job rather than the place she came from even if it was also her job.

---

You may further want to check:

- All the possible
  [usages](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/of_1)
  of "of"
- All the possible
  [usages](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/from)
  of "from"